# Cocoapods nested private libraries

Tags: cocoapods

I have private project (library) A with podspec
then
I have created podfile in project B with:
pod 'A', :path => "../A/" 
and also podspec for B
then I would like to use project B with all dependencies (also private project A) in project C so I created Podfile in project C with:
pod 'B', :path => "../../frameworks/B/"

In project C I can see files from project B also public libraries like AFNetworking but there is not imported my private library A.

I have also tried to add s.dependency to podspec of library B to library A but using :path generates error and without if it doesn't work because it's probably looking into public libraries.

What am I missing? How may I import library with all private libraries?

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but it looks like you need to specify your `B`'s dependency on `A` in `B.podspec`.  It looks like you're trying to specify it's dependencies in a `Podfile` and that is wrong.

There is another problem that you'll soon run into: You can't specify `:path` in a podspec. In order to use private pods you'll need to create a private repo.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html